# Why does innerHTML return "undefined" when used with nodeList but it works with a single object?

Tags: javascript, this, innerhtml

I want to show an alert with the name of the buttons when clicking on them.
If I change `this.innerHTML` to `leButtons.innerHTML` returns 'undefined'. But when I try the same with a single button *(the code in the comments)* it works.

```js
var leButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < leButtons.length; i++){
   leButtons[i].onclick = function() {
       returnColor(this.innerHTML)
   }
 }

 function returnColor (xxx) {
   alert (xxx);
 }

/*
var singleButton = document.getElementById('buttonX');
singleButton.onclick = function() {
    darColor(singleButton.innerHTML)
};

function darColor (xxx) {
  alert (xxx)
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section>
      <button id="buttonX">BLUE</button>
      <button>RED</button>
      <button>PINK</button>
      <button>GREEN</button>
    </section>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would you expect `.innerHTML` of a list of elements to return?

Comment: `leButtons` is, as you said, a node list, not a single element! Why would a list have inner HTML? A list contains elements, it's not logical to have properties of single elements on the list. It would work with `leButtons[i].innerHTML` but only if you change `var i` to `let i`, otherwise `i` will have an unexpected value at the time when that part of the runs (because it gets modified in every loop iteration)

Answer (score 0):

@person as the right idea, but one thing he has wrong is that leButtons is not an array but a nodeList. NodeLists do not have the built in methods that an array has. By using the spread operator you can convert it to an array though. Functionally, they are the same, but it's much cleaner using map.

```
var leButtons = [...document.getElementsByTagName('button')];

leButtons.map(button => (button.onclick = () => alert(button.innerHTML)));
```

Comment: And what is 'i'?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection`. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. `NodeList` would support `forEach` without spreading (except for IE). There is no actual use for `Array#map` here.

Answer (score -1):

`leButtons` is an array of HTML elements which means it has no property `innerHTML`. You need to use `leButtons[i].innerHTML` to get the `innerHTML` property of the button you're currently on in the for loop.

```
var leButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < leButtons.length; i++){
   leButtons[i].onclick = function(){    returnColor(leButtons[i].innerHTML)     };
}

function returnColor (xxx) {
   alert (xxx);
}
```

Comment: It is not an array. It is a  live HTMLCollection. And your code will NOT work. You introduced the infamous for loop bug.